# Сортировка бинарного дерева

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

Есть вот такая вот программа которая входящие данные забивает в бинарное дерево, а потом считает количество обращений к элементам. Нужно после выведения массива отсортированного по алфавиту вывести массив отсортированный по количеству обращений к элементам. Как это можно сделать? Нужно создавать отдельный массив, забивать элементами бинарного дерева и его уже сортировать или есть еще варианты как это можно сделать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int count;
    char str1[32];
    char str2[32];
    Node *r, *l;
};

void show(Node *&Tree)
{
    if (Tree != NULL)
    {
        show(Tree->l);
        cout << Tree->count<<" " << Tree->str1<<" "<<Tree->str2<<endl;
        show(Tree->r);
    }


}

void addNode(char* x,char* y,Node *&MyTree)
{
    if (NULL==MyTree)
    {
        MyTree = new Node;
        strcpy_s(MyTree->str1, x);
        strcpy_s(MyTree->str2, y);
        MyTree->count = 0;
        MyTree->l = MyTree->r = NULL;
    }
    if (MyTree != NULL){


        int k = strcmp(x, MyTree->str1);

        if (k < 0)
        {
            if (MyTree->l != NULL) addNode(x, y, MyTree->l);
            else
            {
                MyTree->l = new Node;
                MyTree->l->l = MyTree->l->r = NULL;
                strcpy_s(MyTree->l->str1, x);
                strcpy_s(MyTree->l->str2, y);
                MyTree->l->count = 0;
            }
        }

        if (k > 0)
        {
            if (MyTree->r != NULL) addNode(x, y, MyTree->r);
            else
            {
                MyTree->r = new Node;
                MyTree->r->l = MyTree->r->r = NULL;
                strcpy_s(MyTree->r->str1, x);
                strcpy_s(MyTree->r->str2, y);
                MyTree->r->count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

void count(char* x,Node *&MyTree)
{
    int k = strcmp(x, MyTree->str1);
    if (k == 0)
    {
        MyTree->count += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (k<0)
        {
            count(x, MyTree->l);

        }
        if (k>0)
        {
            count(x, MyTree->r);
        }
    }


}


    void sort(Node *&Tree)
    {

    }

int main()
{
    Node *Tree = NULL;
    char x[32];
    char y[32];

    while (x != "yyy")
    {
        cin >> x;
        if (strcmp(x, "yyy") == 0)break;
        cin >> y;
        addNode(x, y, Tree);
    }


    while (x != "yyy")
    {
        cin >> x;
        if (strcmp(x, "yyy") == 0)break;
        count(x, Tree);

    }

    show(Tree);
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, лучше отдельный массив.

Comment: Можно конечно. Есть вариант "сквозного поиска по номеру в дереве" (т.е. каждая ветвь имеет свой номер до перестроения) - тогда не строя массив - сравниваете. Если `условие(ветвь[i],ветвь[i+1])` отрицательное - делаете перестановку (перестраивается дерево, нумерация в ветвях поменяется). И повторяем перебор ветвей по номерам снова. Недостаток - проигрыш в скорости (хотя на современных ПК... для тренировки можно ).

Comment: А делать сквозной перебор веток прийдётся как в случае с массивом - так и в случае без массива.